# IndexError when applying setblocking(0) for a Blender3D Python script

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, blender

I'm currently running a script with Blender3D I ported from Python 2+ to Python 3+ with the help of someone from Stackoverflow. The script creates communication between a OMRON PLC (Programmable logic computer) and Blender/Python3+. The script uses TCP communication to write and read the PLC's memory. After the port the script ran properly in Blender the only problem it creates a massive amount of lag and forces Blender to run at 6 fps.

> Python sockets are blocking by default. What that means is that when you call `socket.read()` the function will not return until your data has been read or there is an error on the socket. i.e. The socket "blocks" execution until the operation has completed. Because your code gets blocked in the `recv()` call, your game freezes." [LINK](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?281324-Running-Game-Engine-while-reading-data-wirelessly)

In the link there is said that if you add `setblocking(0)` or `setblocking(False)` or `settimeout(0)` (All the same thing), you will cancel the delay that is caused by the TCP communication.

In order to make it work I had to wrap my `recv()` call in a try, except in order to avoid a socket error: `BlockingIOError: [WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately`.

I've done it like this:

```
    def _recieve(self):
    try:
        pr = self.sock.recv(8)
        length = binstr2int( pr[4:8])
        r = pr + self.sock.recv( length)
        #print (' Recv:' + repr(r))
        return r
    except socket.error as err:
        # Any error but "Would block" should cause the socket to close
        if err.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            self.sock.close()
            self.sock = None
            return
```

However this didn't solve my problem, this creates more problems. The script will run fine but at 6fps when I have setblocking(1). But when I turn it on it gives me a Indexerror:

`File "D:\...", line 126, in disassembled
    asm[ b'ICF'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[16])
IndexError: index out of range'`

This is the area where the error occurs, if I comment out the line it will just say the error occurs in the next `self.rawTcpFrame[17]` for example:

```
    def disassembled(self):
    asm = {
           b"header"   : binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[ 0: 4] ),
           b'length'   : binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[ 4: 8] ),
           b'command' : binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[ 8:12] ),
           b'errCode' : binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[12:16] ),
    }
    if( asm[b'command'] == 2) :
        asm[ b'ICF'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[16])
        asm[ b'RSV'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[17])
        asm[ b'GCT'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[18])
        asm[ b'DNA'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[19])
        asm[ b'DA1'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[20])
        asm[ b'DA2'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[21])
        asm[ b'SNA'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[22])
        asm[ b'SA1'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[23])
        asm[ b'SA2'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[24])
        asm[ b'SID'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[25])
        asm[ b'MRC'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[26])
        asm[ b'SRC'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[27])
        if self.fromRaw :
            #decode from response
            asm[ b'MRES'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[28])
            asm[ b'SRES'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[29])
            asm[b'response'] = self.rawTcpFrame[30:]
        else :
            asm[b'cmd'] = self.rawTcpFrame[28:]
    return asm
```

The entire script can be found [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jtlixga6ogoniyi/OmronFINS_Communicatie_Script_Py34_SO.py)

Comment: I'm not sure if I did this right, but it results in more errors. I've tried wrapping them in try, except but this messes with something else: `File "D:\...", line 177, in __str__
    return b''.join([ k + b':' + bytes(str(asm[k]), 'utf-8') + b' ' for k in list(asm.keys())]).decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your message is not long enough (sequence is shorter than 17). You should test length of frame, or use `zip` and slice to be sure, you don't try to call index that does not exist:

```
tags = (b'ICF', b'RSV', b'GCT', 
    b'DNA', b'DA1', b'DA2', 
    b'SNA', b'SA1', b'SA2', 
    b'SID', b'MRC', b'SRC')

for tag, data in zip(tags, self.rawTcpFrame[16:]):
    asm[tag] = binstr2int(data)
```

or you can wrap everything in `try: ... except IndexError:` and handle too short frame there.

Comment: This messes with a different line in the program, check the comment under my question. Thanks.

Comment: Probably you should return `{}` in your `except...` clause, if you decided to catch error instead of using `zip` / slice approach. Somewhere you need to decide what to do with missing data, and this is up to you to decide where and what to do. But that's another problem and deserves new question. Just be sure you prepare http://www.sscce.org/ next time...